# New command using if/then statement based on cleveref values?

Tags: conditionals, cleveref, ifthenelse, sv-classes

I have a special command defined called \Exerref which works on labels, much like \Cref. Would it be possible to create a new command, let's call it \Sref, that invokes either \Exerref or \Cref based on what the value of \nameref is? For example, if \nameref returns "Exercise", use \Exerref; otherwise, use \Cref. Is such a thing possible in LaTeX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The refcount package offers a command to get the nameref value:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,refcount,etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\section{exercise}\label{testA}
\section{öäüß$abc$}\label{testB}

\makeatletter
\protected@edef\test{\getrefbykeydefault{testA}{name}{}}
\ifdefstring{\test}{exercise}{true}{false}

\protected@edef\test{\getrefbykeydefault{testB}{name}{}}
\ifdefstring{\test}{exercise}{true}{false}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I guess I should have specified thad I was interested more in getting the nameref of environments (theorem, etc.). Can your code be modified to handle this?

Comment: @Skeptic well you (again) didn't provide a complete example in your question and so missed out important details. I will not correct or expand on my answer, I have other things to do now. You will have to work with what you got and try it out yourself. Next time you want a good answer spent a bit more time on a good question.

Comment: I'm very sorry. Thank you for your time and help.